# Repeated cells in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

this is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Maledetta"];
if (cell == nil) {
    UIViewController *c;
    if (!IS_IPAD) c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsRow" bundle:nil];
    else c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsRow_ipad" bundle:nil];
    cell = (NewsRowController*)c.view;

    if ([titleArray count] > 0) {
        [(NewsRowController*)cell setCellDataWithName:[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  
                                              andDate:[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                                                  day:[dayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                                month:[monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [c release];
}
return cell;
}
```

Why it show me only 4 row and after that repeat the first for fourth other time until ten???

```
+-----------------------+
| A
+-----------------------+
| B
+-----------------------+
| C
+-----------------------+
| D
+-----------------------+
| A (repeated)
+-----------------------+
| B (repeated)
+-----------------------+
| C (repeated)
+-----------------------+
| D (repeated)
+-----------------------+
| A (repeated)
+-----------------------+
| B (repeated)
+-----------------------+
```

Ah, `[titleArray count]` is equal to `10`.
`kCustomCellID` is correct.

thanks.
A

Comment: I would suggest stepping through with the debugger and checking your values one at a time. You can use "po object" to print out the raw details of an object if need be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only populating the cell if it's not found in the table's cell queue. If it IS found, you're not overwriting it with the contents for that value of indexPath.row.

Try this instead:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Maledetta"];
if (cell == nil) {
    UIViewController *c;
    if (!IS_IPAD) c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsRow" bundle:nil];
    else c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsRow_ipad" bundle:nil];
    cell = (NewsRowController*)c.view;
    [c release];

 }

 if ([titleArray count] > 0) {
        [(NewsRowController*)cell setCellDataWithName:[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  
                                              andDate:[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                                                  day:[dayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                                month:[monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Also, the check of [titleArray count] is probably redundant. You're using that to give the number of cells in section for this table, right? If that's zero, it won't even get here.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Maledetta"]`, the table view looks for cells in its cache that aren’t on-screen anymore. It finds your cells and uses those instead. Implement `-prepareForReuse` on your cells, then add an `else` clause in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation to handle reused cells.