# How to avoid selecting other cells that have the same indexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I've been struggling with this issue for weeks and still have not found one solution. No one really gave me an answer on SO and have not found anything that helps my issue either.

When making a change of a cell's content's color, position, whatever, other cells with the same indexPath also get modified.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (self.cell == nil) {
    self.cell = [[SearchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```

This is how I create cells. Help..!

**EDIT**

This is a slide-out view implemented in each cell. When you swipe to right on a cell, it shows up from the left but even though only the selected cell's content should be modified, several other cell's slide-out menu also come out.

This is how I implement slide-out menu in my custom cell class.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
self.optionView = [[OptionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width , self.contentView.frame.size.width)];
    self.optionView.delegate = self;
    [self.contentView addSubview: self.optionView];
```

OptionView' delegate - called when swiped to the right

```
-(void)handleGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)shouldOpenMenu{
POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animation];
    anim.property = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:kPOPViewFrame];
    anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(-self.frame.size.width/4, 0, self.optionView0.frame.size.width, self.optionView0.frame.size.height)];
    anim.springBounciness = 11;
    anim.springSpeed = 5;
    [self.optionView0.layer pop_addAnimation:anim forKey:@"spring0"];
```

Comment: What do you mean "other cells with the same index path". A cell doesn't have an index path and there should only be a single cell at each index path.

Comment: Ok... Why are you storing the cell in a property? You shouldn't be storing the cells at all.

Comment: Ah.. I saw some tutorial doing that so I just followed it... Let me try if it works after fixing that. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm nope, it still does the same thing. When I modify a cell's content, some other cells' contents get modified as well..

Comment: Can you show more code. You're not modifying any content here.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: ok, but where are you changing the content? At the moment you are only showing creation of cells. Nothing is changing.

Comment: It's the optionView's delegate.. when I swipe to the right, optionView.delegate gets called and the animation happens. BTW just realized indexPaths' are repetitive.. it gives me 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ... That's why when I change one thing, other cells with the same indexPaths' get modified.

Comment: Not sure why are you not sharing all relevant code here. Unless you will not connect the dots by sharing relevant code, no one will be able to get you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: optionView's delegate method has nothing to do with cell's indexPaths mysteriously being repeated but ok there I posted..! Updated question.

Comment: Found out some people have the same issue as mine and tried to fix it by using one of their answers but nothing has worked yet.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021602/repeated-cells-in-table-view

Answer (score 0):

**First**, each tableview cell has different index path.

**Second**, you never want to save cells at class level properties. Create them locally and return from `cellForIndexPath:`. Your table view will take care of the cell thereon.

**Third**, and very important, cells are reused. So, you should reset the cell before using it. For instance, if you are setting cell colour to red in some condition and then you move the table down and this cell gets discarded and new cell is rendered by re-using the discarded cell. You would want to reset the cell colour to clear if you are not setting cell colour for that row.

Follow these rules and you should be able to fix your issue.

Comment: I'm not even moving the table down and multiple cells' contents are modified when I modify one thing.

Comment: @durazno - please fix second point I mentioned and share your entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  for me to help you. Also share the code where you are changing colour/position.

Comment: I have already.. that did not fix it. One thing I've noticed is that the indexPaths' in fact are repetitive.. it gives me 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ... That's why when I change one thing, other cells with the same indexPaths' get modified.. I don't know how this is happening.